# Laravel relationship belongsToMany with composite primary keys

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, composite-primary-key

I have 3 tables and I'm trying to make relations between order_products and order_products_status_names. I have transition/pivot table named order_product_statuses. The problem are my PK, becuase I have in table orders 3 Pk, and I don't know how to connect this 3 tables throught relationships.
My migrations are:

Table Order Products:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ordinal')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('size');

        $table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id', 'ordinal']);
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}
```

Table Order Product Statuses  - this is my transition/pivot table between order_products and order_product_status_names

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ordinal')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('order_product_status_names');
        $table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id', 'ordinal']);
    });
}
```

And the last one is Order Product Status Names

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product_status_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->primary('id');
    });
}
```

I know that here is relationship blengsToMany in two ways, but I don't know or can I declarate this relation ( from order_products to order_product_status_names and inverse )?

Comment: will take a better look at your requirements tomorrow morning, and see if I can help you out.

Comment: Just a quick question why have you got order_id and product_id in both order_product and order_product_statuses, is this for performance reasons?

Comment: Thank's! I will be waiting and appreciate it!

Comment: Eloquent really isn't designed for composite keys.  You'll save a lot of headache by conforming your db structure to have an `id` primary key in every table.

Comment: Yes, because i Have 3 PK (order_id, product_id and ordinary ), when client order 2 the same products, with the same size, then I have 2 different rows and only ordinal can distinguish them from 1 order. When client take only one from them, then I can add separate statuses

Comment: Can you please update your question with some data as it'll be easier for me to do some testing once I've played around with your table structure (migrations).

Comment: Ypu mean some seeds?

Comment: @wenus Yeah if that's what Laravel calls data, then yes.  I don't usally use migrations myself and prefer to write startup script and update scripts in SQL, as I know the lingo there quite well and don't need to still figure out that interger in Laravel means INT(4) or watever in MySQL, MongoDB etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok haven't spent a great amount of time on this, but this is kind of what I would do.  Also as @Devon mentioned I would probably add ids to each table seeing as Eloquent isn't really designed for composite keys.  As mentioned in one of my comments I usually create startup and update scripts, so the syntax might not be exactly right:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('order_product_statuses_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ordinal')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('size');

        $table->primary('id');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign('order_product_statuses_id')->references('id')->on('order_product_statuses');
    });
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create('order_product_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ordinal')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->primary('id');
        $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('order_product_status_names');
    });
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create('order_product_status_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->primary('id');
    });
}
```

I hope that helps you out a bit.

Comment: On a side note if you want a good starter course on db creation you should Google MongoDB University and signup for the free M101N course.  
I've been doing database development for quite a while now and it was still a great course for me and I actually learnt quite a few things.

Comment: You were right and I had to change my tables... Thnaks for helping

Comment: I'm going through the same problem, and I don't want to have auto increments id as primary key because that really limit the number of arrow ? Right ? What could we do when we are in this kind of problem and don't want to use auto increment ?

Comment: @Toinou I don't quite understand what you're referring to when in your comment "...that really limit the number of arrow ?"?
I usually try figure out what is unique in a collection / table / etc & use that as the primary key.
I think the main reason why auto increment's are used as primary keys are because it makes it easier paging and are unique, although that's just my thoughts & I could be totally off track ;-).
If this doesn't answer your question, please ask a new question & provide the link to the question over here so the community / I can try help you out.
Hope that helps (HTH).